Implementation of Acoustic Wave equation progagation is not scaling at all beyond two threads
In the following OpenMP C code I was expecting that using tempfield could help to write to p1 in one cache line, which in my case is 64 bytes. With two threads I got almost 2x speedup in comparison to the serial code, but when increasing number of cores the speedup is always close 2x. I tried to write the mm loop without using #pragma omp for  because I thought that would be called a large number of times.
System:

Compiler=GCC, version=12.2.0,
Flags= -O3 -funroll-loops -ftree-vectorize - fopenmp
CPU=AMD Ryzen 5 5600G,
OpenMP=4.5

What could be wrong?
Some explanation about variables:

Model velocity size -> (nz=501, nx=1001)
Border points at each side: 800 (Exagerated to test efficiency of code)
CACHE_SZ: 16
NDERIV: 3
nbx=2601,
nbzcache=(2101)/16

#pragma omp parallel default(none)                                             \
    shared(p1, p2, wavemovie, isrc, srcindex, ishot, nbz, idxs, deriv, ricker, \
               dx, velextend, nbzcache, nbx, i0_extended_model, i0_model,      \
               gamma_x, gamma_z, nx, nxx, nzz, nz, nt, ndt, nshots, nthreads)
{
    int iconv, ii, ix, it = 0;
    int mm;
    int imodel;
    int iz, niz;
    float gama, mgamma, invpgamma;
    float laplacian;
    float tempfield[CACHE_SZ];
    nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
#pragma omp single
    {
        printf("Number of threads used:%d\n", nthreads);
    }
    while (ishot < nshots) {
#pragma omp single
        {
            it = 0;
            srcindex = isrc + idxs * ishot;
        }
#pragma omp for
        for (int iswap = 0; iswap < nxx * nzz; iswap++) {
            p1[iswap] = 0.0;
            p2[iswap] = 0.0;
        }

        //  Forward field time update
        for (it = 0; it < nt; it++) {
#pragma omp for schedule(static)
            for (mm = 0; mm < nbzcache * nbx; mm++) {
                ix = (int)mm / nbzcache;
                niz = mm % nbzcache;
                iz = niz * CACHE_SZ;
                // Loop to write in cachelines
                for (ii = 0; ii < CACHE_SZ; ii++) {
                    imodel = i0_extended_model + ix * nzz + iz + ii;
                    gama = gamma_x[ix + NDERIV - 1] +
                           gamma_z[iz + NDERIV - 1 + ii];
                    mgamma = -(1 - gama) / (1 + gama);
                    invpgamma = 0.5 * (1 - mgamma);
                    laplacian = 2 * deriv[0] * p2[imodel];
                    for (iconv = 1; iconv < NDERIV; iconv++) {
                        laplacian += deriv[iconv] * p2[imodel - iconv];
                        laplacian += deriv[iconv] * p2[imodel + iconv];
                        laplacian += deriv[iconv] * p2[imodel - nzz * iconv];
                        laplacian += deriv[iconv] * p2[imodel + nzz * iconv];
                    }
                    tempfield[ii] = invpgamma * velextend[imodel] * laplacian;
                    tempfield[ii] += invpgamma * 2.0 * p2[imodel];
                    tempfield[ii] += mgamma * p1[imodel];
                }
                for (ii = 0; ii < CACHE_SZ; ii++) {
                    p1[imodel - (CACHE_SZ - 1) + ii] = tempfield[ii];
                }
            }
#pragma omp single
            {
                p1[srcindex] +=
                    -pow(dx, 2.0) * ricker[it] * velextend[srcindex];
                if (it % ndt == 0) {
                    for (ii = 0; ii < nx; ii++) {
                        fwrite(p1 + i0_model + ii * nzz, sizeof(float), nz,
                               wavemovie);
                    }
                }
                swap(&p1, &p2);
            }
        }
#pragma omp single
        {
            ishot++;
            printf("ishot:%d\n", ishot);
            printf("nshots:%d\n", nshots);
        }
    }
}

I still not getting much performance scalability even with the suggested changes. In https://github.com/joanguastalla/OpenMP-Acoustic-Wave-Equation.git there is all files that are need to run tests. The only change that would be needed is on makefile LFLAGS to include the path of your OpenMP library.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I donwloaded your code to play with and arrived at the same observations as you: with 4 threads the speed-up is at best x2.5, which is not very good. I have even timed the main loop on mm alone, and it was the same. The only explanation I can see is that the code is already memory-bound with 2 threads, but I wouldn't bet on that. Or the memory access patterns are bad, but it's quite difficult to check that with all the stuff you are making with the CACHE_SZ and the nested loops...

I have a more general comment, unrelated to OpenMP: your innermost loop is not vectorizable, and I doubt the compiler is able to automatically rearrange the code to find some possible vectorizations. I believe the computaion could be easily 2x or 3x times faster if you were arranging the loops differently in order to  have obvious vectorizations.

@PierU I did a test with a very large model removing writes to p1 and it got an nearly 4x speedup with 4 threads.  So i think that memory access is not the major problem, the problem is the line of code that write to p1 as expected given that this variable is shared and need to be updated several times.

So it would rather be a "false sharing" issue (although it doesn't look really obvious). If it was me, I would rewrite the code with vectorization in mind (and forgot the CACHE_SZ tricks).

Is the p1 array is not allocated with an aligned allocator like posix_memalign(…, 64, size). So the whole CACHE_SIZE trick fails. Especially for very large allocations (handled by calloc through mmap) the allocation will always be misaligned because while the mmap is naturally page-size aligned, malloc needs to store a header, causing a 16 byte misalignment. So you always cause cache-line bouncing storing the result to parts of two cache lines

Without MRE, I cannot test it. I think, the following should allow the fwrite to execute during calculation of the next iteration - you would need a dynamic schedule, as the IO thread will have no time to work:
#pragma omp parallel  default(none) firstprivate(ishot) shared(p1,p2,wavemovie,isrc,srcindex,nbz,idxs,deriv,ricker,dx,velextend,nbzcache,nbx,i0_extended_model,i0_model,gamma_x,gamma_z,nx,nxx,nzz,nz,nt,ndt,nshots,nthreads)
    {
        int iconv,ii,ix,it=0;
        int mm;
        int imodel;
        int iz,niz;
        float gama,mgamma,invpgamma;
        float laplacian;
        float tempfield[CACHE_SZ];
        nthreads=omp_get_num_threads();
        #pragma omp single
        {   
            printf("Number of threads used:%d\n",nthreads);
        }
        for(;ishot<nshots;ishot++){
            #pragma omp single
            {
                it=0;
                srcindex=isrc + idxs*ishot;
            }
            #pragma omp for        
            for(int iswap=0;iswap<nxx*nzz;iswap++){
                p1[iswap]=0.0;
                p2[iswap]=0.0;
            }
        
            //  Forward field time update
            for(it=0;it<nt;it++){
                #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic,CACHE_SZ)
                for(mm=0;mm<nbzcache*nbx;mm++){
                        ix=(int) mm/nbzcache;
                        niz=mm%nbzcache;
                        iz=niz*CACHE_SZ; 
                    // Loop to write in cachelines
                    for(ii=0;ii<CACHE_SZ;ii++){
                        imodel=i0_extended_model + ix*nzz +iz + ii;
                        gama=gamma_x[ix + NDERIV-1] + gamma_z[iz + NDERIV-1 +ii];
                        mgamma=-(1-gama)/(1+gama);
                        invpgamma=0.5*(1-mgamma);
                        laplacian=2*deriv[0]*p2[imodel];
                        for(iconv=1;iconv< NDERIV;iconv++){
                            laplacian+=deriv[iconv]*p2[imodel - iconv];
                            laplacian+=deriv[iconv]*p2[imodel + iconv];
                            laplacian+=deriv[iconv]*p2[imodel - nzz*iconv];             
                            laplacian+=deriv[iconv]*p2[imodel + nzz*iconv];
                        }
                        tempfield[ii]=invpgamma*velextend[imodel]*laplacian;
                        tempfield[ii]+=invpgamma*2.0*p2[imodel];
                        tempfield[ii]+=mgamma*p1[imodel];
                    }
                    for(ii=0;ii<CACHE_SZ;ii++){
                        p1[imodel-(CACHE_SZ-1) + ii]=tempfield[ii];
                    }
                } // barrier waits for IO thread from single nowait before reuse of p2
                #pragma omp single 
                {
                    p1[srcindex]+= -pow(dx,2.0)*ricker[it]*velextend[srcindex];
                    swap(&p1,&p2);
                }
                #pragma omp single nowait
                    if(it%ndt==0){
                        for(ii=0;ii<nx;ii++){
                            fwrite(p2+i0_model + ii*nzz,sizeof(float),nz,wavemovie);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            #pragma omp single
            {
                printf("ishot:%d\n",ishot);
                printf("nshots:%d\n",nshots);
            } // barrier will synchronize p2 writeout across ishot iterations
      }
}

It might also be worth looking into asynchronous IO to perform the write in background.

If the loop on mm take less time than the loop with the fwrite, isn't there a risk of messing up the outputs?

The barrier at the end of the worksharing-loop region waits for the IO thread, so there is no race. With dynamic schedule there is no way to avoid this barrier and allow the IO thread to overlap with more of the ndt it iterations for the output. For more overlap, a third IO-p array might be used that is only written in every ndt-th iteration before writing it out to disk (with clever swapping, an additional copying of p can be avoided). Using asynchronous IO, the code would need to wait for completion of the/all aio_write before entering the iteration that writes again to the IO-p.
